# How can remove margin between items in xaml?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is my xaml code:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestSalesforce"
             x:Class="TestSalesforce.MainPage">

    <StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,0">
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="LOGIN" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Label Text="Email:" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
        <Entry x:Name="txtEmail" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
        <Label Text="Password:" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
        <Entry x:Name="txtPassword" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnLogin" Text="Login"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnClose" Text="Close" Clicked="OnClose"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I try using Margin="0,0,0,0" but it not ok:
This is result:
[image]

How can remove margin between items in xaml?

Comment: What margin do you mean?  If you want the Label and Entry closer together, try specifying a HeightRequest for the Label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have styles that are already gettin applied to the elements. Possibly try settings padding on those elements to 0 (they may not support padding) or if that doesn't work you might need to add a negative margin to counteract the styles.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really help. There still could be style getting inherited from a parent control or by to base styling itself.  Does a negative margin fix your issue? Margin="0,-20,0,0"

Comment: Thank you, with  Margin="0,-20,0,0", android is ok, but with UWP : Entry  will override to label.

Comment: Add the margin platform specific, like you can use different margin for different platforms.

Answer (score 3):

`StackLayout` and `Grid` have `Spacing`-Properties. Spacing describes the gap between each child element in the Layout.
 I think by default a `StackLayouts` `Spacing`-Property is not `0` but something around `2-5`.
Try setting `Spacing="0"` on the stacklayout.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code: Using **Grid** format

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="3">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Controls:Label Grid.Row="0" Font="15" Text="{Binding LabelAddress}"/>
        <StackLayout>
            <Controls:PlaceholderEditor Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding TextAddress}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Margin="0,20,0,0"  Placeholder="Enter Address" PlaceholderColor="{StaticResource LightGray}" AutoSize="TextChanges"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
```

The result like this:

[image: Click Here]

Answer (score 0):

Add `Spacing=0` to your stack layout, so it looks the next:
`<StackLayout Spacing=0 Padding="0,0,0,0">`